# Read More in the actual excerpt

Tags: filters, excerpt, read-more

I'm using WP version 4.4.4. I have some posts where it has a continue reading button and link to the actual excerpt. My problem is the excerpt also has a continue reading button. Here is my code at the end of `functions.php`.

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
global $post;
return '... <a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID). '"> continue reading &raquo;</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Fairly new to WordPress. I searched this site but nothing worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear, but it looks like you simply want to remove the continue reading button from the excerpt. You have already found the offending code. Nothing stops you from modifying it in this way:

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
global $post;
return '';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

To do this properly you must not change the theme file itself, but place this code in the `functions.php` of a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), which further only needs to consist of an almost empty `style.css` file. If a function in a child theme has the same name as in the parent theme it will override the latter.

Comment: This doesn't work. I have a blog page where all my posts are being displayed. Posts which have long content (words more than 99(?)) are being cut off and has a continue reading link. Upon clicking the continue reading link, I will now be redirected to the actual post. Problem is there is also continue reading link in that page and I can't read the whole post.

Comment: This sounds like something different from your original question. Either the link of the archive page is not to the single post or the template that should produce the single post doesn't do it.

Comment: The link is working fine. I'm being redirected to the post, but there still is the continue reading link..

Comment: So that means the template (normally `single.php`) doesn't ignore the more tag, as it should.

Comment: Okay. So in my content.php, when I changed the_excerpt(); to the_content the continue reading link is now gone. But in the blog page where the continue reading should appear is now also gone.

Comment: Right, so there is only one theme template for both your archive and your single pages. That's bad and should be solved by the person who designed the theme.

Comment: I solved it! I just don't know if I did it the clean way. I made a content-single.php file and copy paste what's in my content.php and changed the_excerpt() to the_content();.

Comment: That's exactly how it should be done.

Comment: @Hiei Could you please accept the other answer, so this question will be marked as 'solved' by the system. Else it will keep popping up.

Answer (score 0):

[ added answer to enable closure of the question]

After discussion in comments under the other answer the problem seems to be not with the filter, but with a missing template for single posts/pages.